# RESTkit, CoreData: process object right before trasferring it to CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a problem.
I have iOS client app that has to allow multiple users to log in and store their data locally.
Data is synchronized with RESTful service, and the latest snapshot along with user's changes should be stored locally for all users.

Previously this app was implemented with SQLlite as data storage engine.
Now I would like to migrate to CoreData.

What do I have:

- server returns me entities for current user. User ID is not sent, as the user authorizes and gets their session;
- I know who is logged in an should store all data for this particular user. In order to do that I need to say CoreData to store the object for the user with ID=12345.

The problem is:

- I have to tell CoreData to store the particular object associated with particular user's ID.
- I need a way to somehow alter the object mapped with RESTkit - setting proper ID field for it.

This task was straight and simple with SQLlite but looks problematic with CoreData.
I am still thinking that I don't know something about CoreData asking you to help me with clarifications or useful links.

Comment: What request do you make (is the user id in the path / parameters / source object somewhere)?

Comment: @Wain there is no user id. We use temporary access token to communicate with the server (like it is usually). We identify user locally by login name.

Comment: So there isn't a good way to do it. Hacky, you could add the id as a parameter in the request so you can map it back again (requires RestKit dev branch). Non-hacky is to update and re-save the objects returned in the mapping result.

Comment: @Wain thanks we also came to this opinion. So we'll use sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do it.

Hacky, you could add the id as a parameter in the request so you can map it back again (requires RestKit dev branch at time of writing).

Non-hacky is to update and re-save the objects returned in the mapping result.

Alternatively you could use one operation to download the JSON, then mutate it, then run another operation to map it.

Comment: thanks. We also ended up with the same workarounds. The problem is that all these are workarounds and not straight solutions. That's why we decided to stick to SQLite as it is powerful and provides straight solution.